# How to fix that an Android Cordova App in background changes all setIntervals below 1s upto 1s?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview, setinterval

I have an Android App written in Cordova. In this app I call a setInterval function with an interval of 100ms. When I am in foreground everything is fine but whenever I go to background I noticed that the function is called every 1s instead of 100ms.

A code for testing is this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Tick: " + new Date().getTime());
}, 100);
```

I really need this method to be called every 100ms in background. Furthermore, the device is always attached to a power supply so any performance related optimisations in the background I can ignore if it helps.

Does anybody know how I manage that the setInterval function is called every 100ms and not 1s when the app is in background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for two days and the only solution I found is a workaround based on the [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode).

Whenever you go to the background you can set the visibility of the webview to Visible with this method in your Java code

```
appView.getEngine().getView().dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.VISIBLE))
```

then the interval is back to 100ms.

Sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity implements LifecycleObserver {
    /* .. other code .. */

    // init go to background observer
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onToBackground() {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                appView.getEngine().getView().dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 1000); // wait a second to make sure we are in background state
    }

    /* .. other code .. */
}
```

where appView is your CordovaWebView in your CordovaActivity.

Hope it helps if you have the same problem. If there is a better solution please let me know!

Comment: actually this answer only worked if there is not much load on the device. if there is a huge amount of load, it goes back to 1s. Eventually I did it in this way that I created a native setInterval method (and btw. also setTimeout) and called this one instead of the JS one.